# NullPointerException thrown when getting a specified mapped key

Tags: java, android

Am trying to get a specified key value from a string but nullpointerexception is constantly thrown when the code reaches this line:

```
splitter.httpHost = ((String)splitter.map.get("Host")).replaceAll(":([\\d]+)", "");
```

Here is the complete code:

```
public class InjectDataSplitter {

private String tmpHost;
private String b;
private int httpPort = 0;
private String httpHost;
private HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
private String e;
private String f;

public InjectDataSplitter(String str) {
    this.tmpHost = str;
}

public static InjectDataSplitter get_data_splitter(String str) {

    InjectDataSplitter splitter = new InjectDataSplitter(str);

    splitter.b = splitter.tmpHost;

    //Split the supplied string
    String arraystring[] = splitter.tmpHost.split("\r\n", 2);

    for(int x = 0; x < arraystring.length; x++) {
        String arraystring1[] = arraystring[x].split(" ");

        for(int y = 0; y < arraystring1.length; y++) {
            splitter.e = arraystring1[y];
            splitter.f = arraystring1[y];
        }

        String arraystring2[] = arraystring[x].replace("\r\n\r\n", " ").split("\r\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < arraystring2.length; i++) {

            try {

            String arraystring3[] = arraystring2[i].split(":");
            splitter.map.put(arraystring3[1], arraystring3[2]);

            } catch(Exception e) {

            }

            splitter.httpHost = ((String)splitter.map.get("Host")).replaceAll(":([\\d]+)", "");
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":([\\d]+)");

            if(!splitter.e.equals("CONNECT")) {

                String s1 = splitter.f;
                s1 = splitter.b;

                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);

                if(!matcher.find()) {
                    //find each match in turn
                    //find each match in turn
                    int j = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)); //Access a submatch group

                    boolean flag = splitter.e.equals("CONNECT");

                    if(flag){
                        j = 443;
                    }else{
                        j = 80;
                    }
                    splitter.httpPort = j;

                }
            }

        }
    }

    return splitter;
}
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Splitters map hasn't been initialized?

Comment: So what is the value of str argument you are calling the get_data_splitter function with?

Comment: I suspect the [1] and [2] in the statement doing the map.put. Sure it shouldn'b be [0] and [1]? - Why don't you provide the String that's being mangled by the piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException comes when you try to invoke a method on a null object.

If error is coming on that line as you say then that means ((String)splitter.map.get("Host")) is null.

Answer (score 0):

You get a NullPointerException, because something in this part of code is null

```
 splitter.map.get("Host")
```

Debug and find out, what exactly is null. I would think, that the `map` does not contain the string Host. There is one deadly dangerous part of your code, that can hide a problem when you try to put into the `map`

```
catch(Exception e) {

}
```

There may be exceptions, but in general it is bad to hide the exceptions. Write at least this:

```
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And see if there is some exception.

Answer (score 0):

The string argument am calling in the above class is this:

code:

```
String str = A.c(socks.getInputStream());
DataSplitter dataSplitter = DataSplitter.get_data_splitter(str);
```

I debugged further and saw that map doesn't contain any string key value called "Host". Am out of ideas on how to get the mapped in key using hashmap. Please any further suggestions on how to go about restructuring my code?

Comment: Don't answer your own question - edit the question if you provide additional information! - AND WHAT IS THE VALUE OF `str`???